# Caching google speed insights - Google captcha problems

Tags: performance, .htaccess, caching, pagespeed

I am trying to improve my page speed and i use googles speed insights [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

One of the things i have to do is to cache my javascript, css and images.

So far i found this code which i put into my `.htaccess` file and it did eliminate all of the caching problems except 1.

```
 <Files *.js> Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=604800" </Files>
 <Files *.css> Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=604800" </Files>
 <Files *.jpg> Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=604800" </Files>
 <Files *.jpeg> Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=604800" </Files>
 <Files *.png> Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=604800" </Files>
```

When i run page speed insights i now get this error:

Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js (5 minutes)
```

What do i do here if anything, since this is from google?